# Scala type mismatch from Java library

Tags: scala, types, scala-java-interop

I am trying to use a Java library ([Hipster](https://github.com/citiususc/hipster/)) with Scala. Running the example on the front page, I get this type error message which I can't make sense of:

My attempt so far was to try convert Java <==> Scala Doubles and Strings to no avail.

```
<console>:23: error: type mismatch;
 found   : es.usc.citius.hipster.model.problem.SearchProblem[scala.Double,String,es.usc.citius.hipster.model.impl.WeightedNode[scala.Double,String,java.lang.Double]]
 required: es.usc.citius.hipster.model.problem.SearchProblem[A,S,N]
       val sol = Hipster.createDijkstra(pX)
```

Code sample:

```
import es.usc.citius.hipster.algorithm.Hipster
import es.usc.citius.hipster.model.problem.SearchProblem

val graph = GraphBuilder.create[String,Double]().connect(
  "A").to("B").withEdge(4.0).
  connect("A").to("C").withEdge(2.0).
  connect("B").to("C").withEdge(5.0).
  connect("B").to("D").withEdge(10.0).
  connect("C").to("E").withEdge(3.0).
  connect("D").to("F").withEdge(11.0).
  connect("E").to("D").withEdge(4.0).
  createDirectedGraph()

// Create the search problem. For graph problems, just use
// the GraphSearchProblem util class to generate the problem with ease


val pX = GraphSearchProblem.startingFrom("A").in(graph).takeCostsFromEdges().build();

// Search the shortest path from "A" to "F"
val sol = Hipster.createDijkstra(pX)
```

Comment: Try passing `java.lang.Double` instead of a simple Double

Comment: That didn't help. interestingly, `createDepthFirstSearch` works (instead of `createDijkstra`). The generic signature is bit different. Will look into it more.